# is sql transaction can apply in web application

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, web-applications, transactions

Can I use sql transactions in web applications?

I.e. when a user starts filling forms the transaction begins. But when another user fills the form at the same time does he get another transaction?

The form is complete when three pages of data are submitted by the user. The data are saved to different tables after filling the specific pages; after completing all form pages the commit should be invoked.

Does this work for a web application where there may be multiple users at same time filling in forms?
I used this method but I get errors that the database/server is not responding/busy.

Is there is any other option to avoid incomplete form submission?

Answer (score 0):

Using a transaction on a forum application is not going to be a good idea, if 2 users are trying to submit new threads at around the same, User 2 would be blocked from accessing/updating tables with the data they are submitting until User 1's transaction is committed.

Comment: @daw is there is any other option. my forum collect more data to many tables in wizard like windows. if the user stops entering the data or incomplete for submission may lead to occurrence of unwanted data in my database

Comment: I recommend that you add in some specific where clause conditions to whatever query you use to insert to your tables(s) so that you willy only insert data to the table if all the fields meet a certain criteria such as no fields being null or checking that a certain field is at least a certain length.